# Google API bad input string

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, typeerror

I am having an issue authenticating through the Google API system using the `googleapis` library. I have tried multiple other libraries as well without success.

The error I am getting can be seen below. It is

> TypeError: Bad input string

[image: Bad input string]

I have a .json file that was created through the Google API Console, the service account has all permissions available as well as domain wide delegation. I have tried it without DwD as well which didn't work either.

The code I am using to authenticate is as follows:

```
let { google } = require('googleapis');
let privatekey = require('../config/keys/CCKey.json');

let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics']);
//authenticate request

jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected!");
    }
});
```

The JSON file that was generated by the Google API Console is as follows:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx-1xx70xxxx4xx6",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxx-service-account@xxxx-1xxx6.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1xxxx2",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem might be to do with setting Managing API Client Access on your G Suite domain. This will need to be set by someone with Super Admin Access.

For some further information see the following link:

[Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

And browse down to the section **Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account**

In your case, the Client Name would be your `project_id` from your service account JSON  (xxx-1xx70xxxx4xx6) and you would need to set your scopes to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics`